# Goal Calculator compound value not correct

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create goal calculator where user enter future required amount and know how much monthly investment required.

Ex: If i want 1200 Rs after 1 year how much monthly investment required with compound.

HTML file here

```
  <input type="number" id="goalAmt" placeholder="Goal Amount" required/>
  <input type="number" id="goalYear" placeholder="Year" required/>
  <input type="number" id="goanAnnualrate" placeholder="Annual Rate" required/>
  <button id="submitBtn" onClick="GoalCalculate();">Submit</button>
```

I have written below javascript.

```
function GoalCalculate() {

    var investment = parseInt(document.getElementById("goalAmt").value);
    var annualRate =
        parseInt(document.getElementById("goanAnnualrate").value);
    var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;
    var years = parseInt(document.getElementById("goalYear").value);
    var months = years * 12;
    var futureValue = 0;
    var goalVal = 0;
    var currency = "INR";


    goalVal = investment * (1 + monthlyRate) / (months);

    document.getElementById("MI_req").innerHTML = currency + " "
        (~~goalVal);

}
```

Comment: Do you have a any test case? what to input and expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: what's your question? You forgot to describe any kind of problem or what specifically you need help with. What are you expecting the code to do, and what does it do instead? Please give a more precise description. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the calculation is right, you just forgot to add a `+` at the end where you show the result

```js
function GoalCalculate() {
  var investment = parseInt(document.getElementById("goalAmt").value);
  var annualRate =
    parseInt(document.getElementById("goanAnnualrate").value);
  var monthlyRate = annualRate / 12 / 100;
  var years = parseInt(document.getElementById("goalYear").value);
  var months = years * 12;
  var futureValue = 0;
  var goalVal = 0;
  var currency = "INR";

  goalVal = investment * (1 + monthlyRate) / (months);
  document.getElementById("MI_req").innerHTML = currency + " " + (~~goalVal);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="goalAmt" placeholder="Goal Amount" required/>
<input type="number" id="goalYear" placeholder="Year" required/>
<input type="number" id="goanAnnualrate" placeholder="Annual Rate" required/>
<button id="submitBtn" onClick="GoalCalculate()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="MI_req"></h1>
```

Comment: Sorry i have already added +. My question is currently my calculation is not correct.

Comment: @ChetanThakur Do you have a any test case? what to input and expected output

Comment: expected amount will be 95 INR  per month if Goal Amt- 1200, Year -1, Annual Rate - 10 .

Comment: kindly check this one. http://www.capitalsolutions.in/calculatorGoal.php